# Inserting Data into database using Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am developing browser helper object to get client information like IP, URL, data time, etc. I am getting this information but it can't store it to the database. For storing purpose I use web service to store data into database. Web service direct store information correctly but getting information from bho it can't store data into database. And not showing any error, I don't know what's the problem.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MyBHO
{
    [
    ComVisible(true),
    Guid("8a194578-81ea-4850-9911-13ba2d71efbd"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
    ]
    public class BHO : IObjectWithSite
    {

        string ip = new 
        System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
        string  datetimenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        WebBrowser webBrowser;
        HTMLDocument document;
```

In this function I send data to web service to save data into database but when bho running it displays data on form but not storing in database.

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("your log infomation: :" + ip+ "/n" + URL.ToString() + "/n"+ datetimenow);
    logReciever.LogRecieverSoapClient client = new logReciever.LogRecieverSoapClient();
    client.insertData(URL.ToString(), ip, datetimenow);

}
```

and

```
public int SetSite(object site)
{
    if (site != null)
    {
        webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete +=
          new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 +=
           new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete -=
          new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 -=
          new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
        webBrowser = null;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Advance thanks for helping.

Comment: logReciever.LogRecieverSoapClient client = new logReciever.LogRecieverSoapClient();
        client.insertData(URL.ToString(), ip, datetimenow);

Comment: i add web service reference and then use soap client to create object and use method to insert data

Comment: Never mind. I can see the web reference and that should be working. See if you have skipped anything in the web service.

Comment: every thing is working. just through bho data didn't store in database.

Comment: i separate check web service its working!!!!!!!!!!